# how to frame a sql query to check if the value of the column is all spaces

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, space, spaces

I have only spaces as values of rows in a column of length 121 chars.

I want to write a query in oracle to check whether the column string is only spaces.

for e.g. if say for column address. a row contains only spaces(all 121 chars are spaces).

i want a query that will check if the row contains only spaces.

select * from table where address <> ' ';

but this isnt working it only checks for 1 space. i want the query to check for all 121 spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You could just run a TRIM on the column. Depending on your DBMS, the Null string is treated as either a `NULL` or as an empty string ''. But for Oracle where the empty string is treated as a `NULL`, you should be able to do:

`select * from table where LTRIM(RTRIM(address)) IS NOT NULL`

Note that TRIM removes all whitespace, not just the space character.

Comment: Whitespace is Tabs, Carriage Returns/Linefeeds, and Space characters. As another answer says, a large field defined as CHAR is usually a symptom of bad design.

Answer (score 1):

If you're checking for 121 spaces as a learning exercise then that's OK, but if you're storing 121 spaces in a column for a production application you may have a bad design.

If the column type is `CHAR` it should probably be changed to `VARCHAR` (or `VARCHAR2` in Oracle). If it already is `VARCHAR`/`VARCHAR2` you should store an empty string as, well, an empty string.

If you need the value padded to 121 spaces, take care of that when you query it:

- Oracle: `SELECT RPAD(NVL(address, ' '), 121) FROM myTable`
- MySQL: `SELECT RPAD(address, 121, ' ') FROM myTable`

If you want to find out if the value is empty, remember that Oracle treats an empty string as `NULL`. MySQL treats it as an empty string:

- Oracle: `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE address IS NULL`
- MySQL: `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE address = ''`

Answer (score 0):

use `REPLACE()` function and compare it's result to null

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE REPLACE(address,' ') IS NULL;
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/935e0/4)